# Storage optimisation problem specific for aws S3

Tags: c++, algorithm, amazon-s3, optimization, storage

Let me start with a bit of background , We are providing free email service for millions of users and we are currently using AWS to host our service.
our current backend architecture is as follow:

- Mail received on our smtp servers
- Mail pushed to the Q
- Mail retrieved from Q and parsed by our workers
- Mail mime && attachments are pushed to aws S3 for storage

  AWS S3 is the cheapest option regarding to storage alone but also includes extra pricing for requests for the service (https://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/).
  it also contains something called "lifecycle policy" which defines the rules for each object in the S3 , on our architecture the lifecycle policy is defined in a way that each object after 30 days will be moved to S3 IA (Infrequent Access - the S3 IA is like the standard S3 except the storage price is 50% cheaper from the standard but the requests price is higher).

There is one more thing to mention before i can describe my problem , Object in the S3 standard storage will only be transferred to the S3 IA if its size is more than 128K (minimum file size on the S3 IA is 128K).

So my problem is as follows:

An average email mime size is around 30-40-50K and after compression it will shrink to 3-4-5K (90% compression - Text!) .
so if we push the email mime to S3 after compression the lifecycle policy will not apply to it and it will remain in the S3 standard forever .
My idea to handle this problem is to create another Q for incoming emails and wait for sufficient amount of emails than compress **each** email and bundle them together for a minimum size of 10MB .
S3 supports the Content-Range header so i can retrieve individual email without retrieving the entire bundled object.
The problem occurs when i need to delete an email which requires me to get the full object , remove the specific email and rePUT it to the S3.
After a quick calculation , this process is highly inefficient.

Any clever suggestions? better algorithm ?

Comment: If my napkin is correct, 100,000,000 5K objects stored in S3 `STANDARD` will cost you only $11.50/month.  Is this even worth your attention?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Hi, we've 12 petabytes of data , so lets assume that all the deleted object are within the price of 0.021gb/m so for a 5K object we are going to pay 0.000000100135803$ and for 1000000000 we will pay 100$ and we've got much more than that .